Staking solana error
I am currently staking solana using phantom wallet but now I want to unstake. The thing is, it says the staking is active and I can't deactivate it.
When I click "unstake" button, it starts "thinking" forever and simply doesn't unstake.
Already tried in the end of the epoch but didn't work.
Is something missing me?
Really apreciate some help, thanks a lot :)

When you unstake, your stake goes through a cooldown period.
The state should change from active to the. Deactivated for you to be able to unstake.
https://solana.com/docs/economics/staking/stake-accounts
